# Mapping an struts2 action based on querystring, rather than path name

Tags: java, struts2, mapping, action, dispatcher

Is there a way to configure struts 2, so that the dispatcher will use the querystring to map the action to invoke?

For example, in the link below, I would like to invoke action blah, not action foo.

http://domain:port/myapp/foo.do?someparameter=blah

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think that is possible with any of the default mappers.

It wouldn't be that bad to create an `Interceptor` that is configured for your `foo` action that checks the value of `someparameter`, and either chains or redirects to your `blah` action.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  Since not possible with default mappers, maybe I'll try creating my own mapper, extending the DefaultActionMapper. I'd give you all a mark up, but my reputation is still below 15 :(

Answer (score 2):

+1 Jeremy: That can do the magic else if you don't want to create an action just create a kinda dispatcher action which will dispatch your request to certain action based on the value of Query String

For e.g

```
Foo action execute();

if (querystring="test") {
    setActionName("Test");
    return "next";
}
```

Based on these control string, you can forward request to certain action.

```
<result name="next" type="redirectAction">${actionName}</result>
```